# Mysql, How to group by columns and select latest date?

Tags: mysql, sql

As you can see from the result in the picture, BASIC_ADJUSTM is a duplicate, i want to group it
and select only the latest one, which has the field value of 2500

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Downvotes are typically provided for questions which are unclear and/or lack research effort. You're ticking all the boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NOT EXISTS` for it as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM employment_informations t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 FROM employment_informations  t2
         WHERE t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id 
           AND t1.field_name = t2.field_name
           AND t2.created_at > t1.created_at)
```

Comment: Wow, I tried it and it works, and it's much shorter. tnx, sir.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to select columns which is not part in group by or not an aggregate function here's how I did it:

```
SELECT *
FROM employment_informations t1
WHERE (t1.employee_id, t1.field_name, t1.created_at) = ANY(
    SELECT 
        t2.employee_id,
        t2.field_name,
        MAX(t2.created_at)
    FROM employment_informations t2
    WHERE t2.effectivity_date = '2021-01-20'
    GROUP BY t2.employee_id, t2.field_name
)
ORDER BY t1.employee_id, t1.field_name
```